# how to assign PHP session value to Javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript

How can I assign the session value to a javascript variable. For example, I want to assign the `$_SESSION['name']` to javascript variable `name`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, four options:

- Set it with php, in the javascript
  `<script type="javascript">var name = "<?php echo $name; ?>";</script>`
- Set a cookie with php, and retrieve it with javascript ([Javascript cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp), [PHP cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp))
- Use jquery Ajax ([Visual Jquery](http://visualjquery.com)) ([Jquery Ajax](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/))
- Set it as a GET variable (append it to the end of the url) ([Like this](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/))